# How to use .format in python to print out the data shape

Tags: python, string.format

I'm trying to print the shape of the dataframe using .format in python

Tried using print statement incorporating `.format` and `.shape` commands

```
df_shape = df.shape
print("The data has Rows {}, Columns {}".format(df_shape[0]))
```

Error I got

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Because `df.shape` is not a list

Answer (score 2):

Do this :

```
df_shape = df.shape print("The data has Rows {}, Columns {}".format(df_shape[0], df_shape[1]))
```

Or this:

```
df_shape = df.shape print("The data has Rows {}, Columns {}".format(*df_shape))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format string contains two simple placeholders, so the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rpartition#str.format) method expects you provide 2 values to replace those placeholders. But you only provided one value to it: `df_shape[0]`

You can fix this by providing explicitely the  two values of your tuple:

```
"The data has Rows {}, Columns {}".format(df_shape[0], df_shape[1])
```

You could also use unpacking, using the splat operator:

```
"The data has Rows {}, Columns {}".format(*df_shape)
```

Or you could name your placeholders and provide only the raw tuple:

```
"The data has Rows {shape[0]}, Columns {shape[1]}".format(shape=df_shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unpack the tuple.

**Ex:**

```
df_shape = df.shape 
print("The data has Rows {}, Columns {}".format(*df_shape))
```

Answer (score 0):

[0] for the first, then [-1] for the last element

```
data = (666, 999)
print("The data has Rows {}, Columns {}".format(data[0], data[-1])
```